# P5.js - Animation Rotation - How to rotate sword 360 degrees?

Tags: animation, rotation, p5.js

Im trying to animate an object, in this example the object is a sword.

The animation is the sword rotating 360 degrees, one time, per button press.

I've drawn the sword, put it in my desired starting/ending position and I've got it to rotate once, but I can't seem to get it to rotate a second time.

Here's what I've got so far...

```
angleMode(DEGREES);

let angle = 150;

push();
translate(100,100);
rotate(angle);
rect(-15,-5,100,10);
pop();

if (key == 'z' && angle <= 150 && angle >= -190){
 angle -= 20;
} else if (angle >= -190){          
 angle = 150;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant to check if the angle <= -190 to reset it back to 150 ?

```js
// ...
} else if (angle <= -190){          
 angle = 150;
}
```

running example snippet:

```js
let angle = 150;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  push();
  translate(100, 100);
  rotate(angle);
  rect(-15, -5, 100, 10);
  triangle(85, -5, 85, 5, 110, 5);
  pop();

  if (keyIsPressed) {
    if (key == "z" && angle <= 150 && angle >= -190) {
      angle -= 20;
      console.log("updated angle", angle);
    } else if (angle <= -190) {
      console.log("angle reset");
      angle = 150;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I really appreciate this! 

I'm actually trying to program the sword to swing once per button press. 

For example, pressing "z" one time (whether you are holding down the key or not) would swing the sword 180 degrees forwards then swing 180 degrees back to its original position. (OR simply swing 360 degrees, one time).

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy to help. What you're describing sounds like animating a sword swing and triggering it with a key pressed. I recommend breaking the problem down: 1. animate the sword swinging once (in a function), 2. handle the presses but also the animation state (e.g. don't swing again until the animation completed), 3. bring the two solutions together in the same sketch. I recommend asking a separate question and post your attempt: good luck!